# Postgres - foreign key on not unique column

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:
[image]

while my items table has the `item_code` column, I can have the same `item_code` multiple times for different `store_id`.

I do want to check on the DB level that my `item_code` exists in my `items` table, but when trying to do so, I get the following error:

`[42830] ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "items".`

Indeed it's not unique, and I can't make it unique.

What I can do in this case to support foreign key check on item_code ?

Comment: You can use triggers instead of a foreign key. Or redesign your schema.

Comment: Why don't your items have unique codes? How else do you identify them?

Comment: I do have unique code, but this code is easier for me and saves me some queries, was curious if that's possible to do a check in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In your case this is not exactly a foreign key. I would suggest that you use a `check` constraint to make sure that `item_code` exists in `items` table, no matter in which store. As you can not do that directly (subqueries are not allowed in check conditions), you will need a simple helper function.

```sql
create function item_code_exists(ic bigint) returns boolean as
$$
 select exists (select from items where item_code = ic);
$$ language sql;
```

and then use a column definition in the other table DDL like this:

```sql
item_ref bigint check (item_code_exists(item_ref))
```

Comment: Unlike a proper foreign key, this will not prevent you from deleting or updating the item though.

Comment: @Bergi Fair enough.

Comment: @Bergi I think that both items and stores do have unique codes in other (nomenclature) tables while the table that the OP calls `items` is actually an availability one that references the above two. This is guessing of course but the field names (item_code, store_id) prompt so. Thus proper foreign keys may refer to the nomenclature tables.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to create a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on the `item_code` column of `items`.  A foreign key must reference a unique or primary key constraint.

Every table should have a primary key!